# I want to use the regex to split the string in java

Tags: java, regex, replace, split, str-replace

Here is what I read from a file:

> (25 "If" "\"First aid.test()\"" ((286 13)) ()

I want this string to be split into

```
25 If "First aid.test()" 286 13
```

How can this be achieved using a regex to split this string?

Comment: I don't see any splitting. You just removed some characters.

Comment: regex used to identify it with pattern.. i think you just need to replace some character with `space`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I want the result to be shown as an array, like [25, If, "First aid.test()", 286, 13]

Comment: @slivia  please remember to Accept the best answer when your question is answered.

Answer (score 1):

Splitting the string cannot produce a substring which was not a part of the original string, e.g. `...test()"` which appeared as `...test()\"` in the original string. However, you could use a regex to find the relevant tokens and then process them as needed.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    String test = "(25 \"If\" \"\\\"First aid.test()\\\"\" ((286 13)) ()";
    Pattern extract = Pattern.compile("[^(\" )]+|(\"(\\\\\\\\|\\\\\"|[^\"])*\")");
    Matcher match = extract.matcher(test);
    List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<>();
    while(match.find()) {
        String token = match.group(0);
        if(match.group(1) != null) {
// FYI: consider using Apache StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(token);
            token = token.substring(1, token.length()-1);
            token = token.replace("\\\"", "\"");
        }
        tokens.add(token);
    }
    System.out.println(tokens);
}
```

**Output:**

> [25, If, "First aid.test()", 286, 13]

Comment: @slivia I have updated my answer to print in the list format, based on your updated requirements.

Comment: Thank you so much. That's what I want

Comment: @slivia [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) is what to do when someone answers your question. To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. There is no need to add a comment on your question or on an answer to say "Thank you".

Answer (score 0):

Edit for your latest comment:
This aint pretty but it will successfully split your string as you described in your comment:

```
String input =  "(25 \"If\" \"\\\"First aid.test()\\\"\" ((286 13)) ()";
input = input.replaceAll("(?<!\\\\)\"|\\\\", "");
input = input.replaceAll("[)](?!\\\")|[(](?![)]\")", "");
input = input.replaceAll("(\".*?\")| ", "_$1");
String[] result = input.split("_+");
```

- First replace: remove all " not preceeded by \ then remove all \
- Second replace: remove all relevant ( and ) https://regex101.com/r/K2LS1c/1
- Third replace: replace everything matching between quotes or spaces with _*match*
- Split on _

This will result in

> [25, If, "First aid.test()", 286, 13]

It really is butt-ugly but it will work for your string...

Comment: There are a lot of cases where this fails. For example, `"If\\"` or `"test(wow(ok))"`

Comment: Yeah, its a pretty bad solution, but we dont know much about the input. You got my vote